# Listen on IPv6 on node.js

Tags: node.js, express, webserver

I have done a lot of research and have not found anything pointing in my way, either it's that they don't have an answer or something, or the answer makes no sense or outdated. but yeah. How do I listen on IPv6 on Node.JS when I know almost nothing about it? I am using express but still can't find any answers for Express either. Does anyone have solutions? If you need more details, I will give them to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i'm not mistaken,

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
   res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.listen(80, 'IPv6 Address')
```